# Trouble With Colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I am currently making a 2D game and I am trying to make my character die whenever his head touches an object, however, he will be walking on the same kind of objects. How do I differentiate when his feet touch something as compared to when his head touches something? Would I use two separate box colliders? If so, how would I code that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using colliders to detect when the player's head touches the ceiling, I would use one collider for the whole body.  Then, use `Physics.Checkbox` to determine whether anything is colliding with the player's head.  For the calculation, you can specify a layer to omit, and naturally one would omit the player's collider.

So, your code might look something like this:

```
if(Physics.Checkbox(center, extents, rotation, playerLayerNumber)) {
    //Handle player death here...
}
```

The only problem being, of course, that your player will die when anything touches their head, if you've got other objects in your scene.  Hope I could help!